# Open new activity using intent on FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, listactivity, fragmentpageradapter

i want open new activity (List Activity) List.java under Tile Strip

how to use intent on the **onCreateView**
 OR 
How To add List On the **onCreateView**

main.java is Sample for Swipe View and Tile Strip on the Eclipse

Main.java :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Create a new Intent and open New Activity


            return ;
        }
    }

}
```

List.Java :

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class List extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        final String[] products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products);

        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, products));


    }
}
```

Comment: what's exactly your issue

Comment: i want add list under Tile Strip I need Code

Comment: Do You want a ListFragment as first tab?

Comment: yes ListFragment on frist tab

Answer (score 0):

Your class `List` should `extends ListFragmen`t instead of `ListActivity`, then in your `getItem` from `SectionsPagerAdapter`, if `position` is `0` returns an istance of the class `List` else return an istance of `DummyFragment`

```
   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
         Fragment fragment = null;

        if (position == 0) {
              fragment = new List();

        } else {
            fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }


        return fragment;
    }
```

your class `List` has to extends `ListFragment`

```
public class List extends ListFragment
```

Comment: List() have error and setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, products)); have error too

Comment: i fix setListAdapter but i cannot fix List()

Comment: can you tell me at least what's the problem?

Comment: new List(); Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Fragment

Comment: check your import. Probably your are importing List from Collection